# Abnormal reaction of grignard reagent

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, redox, halides

My book states that:

> When isopropyl magnesium bromide is added to diisopropyl ketone, the expected tertiary alcohol is not obtained; instead the secondary alcohol; diisopropyl carbinol is obtained resulting from reduction".

I know this has happened due to steric crowding but can anyone tell the mechanism for this?

Comment: https://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/grignard-reaction.shtm see "single electron transfer"

Comment: Compare this reduction with the Meerwein-Pondorff-Verley reduction. https://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/meerwein-ponndorf-verley-reduction.shtm

Answer (score -1):

The reaction you are suggesting is:

[image: given reaction: isopropyl magnesium bromide plus diisopropyl ketone gives diisopropyl carbinol]

[ChemLibreTexts](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Organic_Chemistry_(McMurry)/17%3A_Alcohols_and_Phenols/17.04%3A_Alcohols_from_Carbonyl_Compounds-_Reduction) mention using $\ce{LiAlH_4}$ and $\ce{NaBH_4}$ for the reduction of carbonyls to alcohols:

[image: reduction of carbonyls to alcohols using lithium aluminium hydride and sodium borohydride]

Again, Grignard's reagent does not show.

The [Wikipedia article on Grignard's reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grignard_reaction#:%7E:text=The%20Grignard%20reaction%20%28pronounced%20%2F%C9%A1ri%C9%B2ar%2F%29%20is%20an%20organometallic,is%20important%20for%20the%20formation%20of%20carbon%E2%80%93carbon%20bonds.) also shows conversion of secondary ketones to tertiary alcohols:

[image: Wikipedia Grignard Reaction]

[Organic-chemistry.org](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/grignard-reaction.shtm) shows a similar reaction:

[image: addition of methyl magnesium bromide to diisopropyl ketone]

However, no alcohol is obtained as a product. [Meerwein-Ponndorf-Verley reduction](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/meerwein-ponndorf-verley-reduction.shtm), mentioned in the comments, requires an aluminum catalyst. However, as pointed in the comments, it says "Grignard Reagents will sometimes yield the result of an MPV reduction if the carbonyl carbon is too hindered for nucleophilic addition."

[image: Meerwien-Ponndorf-Verley reduction]

This should answer the question.

Comment: Did you read the whole entry on MPV reduction at organic-chemistry.org that you linked to? Specifically this sentence "Grignard Reagents will sometimes yield the result of an MPV reduction if the carbonyl carbon is too hindered for nucleophilic addition."

Answer (score -2):

The following mechanism results in the secondary alcohol:

[image]

Comment: This answer is just a snap shot of a diagram. Must described what you think in words please.

Comment: Technically this is correct, but I "don't know" why only a hydride ion is transferred. A complete answer gives this reason.

Comment: This proposed diagram is wrong. The grignard reagent is a very strong base and the alpha carbons of the ketone have relatively acidic hydrogens. I think a more likely diagram would be the grignard carbanion abstracting one of the alpha hydrogens, pushing its bonding electrons up to for a double bond with the carbonyl carbon and displacing the carbon-oxygen double bond electrons to a negatively charge oxygen whose charge is counter-balanced by the MgBr+. This is a tautomer of the original ketone and in a protic solvent could probably re-equilibrate to the original ketone form.

Comment: The comment at the end of the original post of " the secondary alcohol; diisopropyl carbinol is obtained resulting from reduction" to me likely means a reduction reaction (LiAlH4 or NaBH4) followed by acid work up. It is worth noting that these conditions would also yield the secondary alcohol from the starting ketone without the application of the Grignard. As a practical note, this would be a very expensive and roundabout way of making an alcohol lol.