# Steric Factors on reaction with grignard reagent

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, hydrolysis, grignard-reagent

[image]
I was asked to find the products X and Y.
For the product X,Here the grignard reagent and even the carbonyl substrate was too sterically hindered to approach the carbonyl center so no reaction would take place, thus the final product will be[image]

I thought the same for Y product .. Here the Carbonyl compound was crowded to approach so no reaction would take place but then I found the answer to be this.
[image]

So for the product Y hydrolysis occured due to presence of dilute HCl but it did not occur for the first one. But why? And was I right about the logic above?

Comment: https://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/grignard-reaction.shtm Scroll a bit down. The grignard reagent used for [Y] is most likely to bulky to deprotonate the $\alpha$ hydrogen.

Comment: @Soumik Das take a look at the reference Avnish Kabaj linked to. Reduction can occur when there is too much hindrance for nucleophilic attack

Comment: @Waylander Hmm. Pretty unusual though.

Comment: @AvnishKabaj That means we will get three products in total; and the reduced one is given as a side product though.. That means the product by SET mechanism will be major, isn't it?

Comment: @Soumik Das I think that was the point of the question

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2G6A.png Looks like the major product will be the reduced form and minor will be the enolized form and surprisingly zero percent addition product.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/106987/abnormal-reaction-of-grignard-reagent